# How to create a folder in SharePoint 2010 document library using REST or HTTP methods

Tags: folder, rest

I am using Java to make calls to the SharePoint REST Interface to get list items of a document library and HTTP methods to upload documents to SharePoint. But, I am having a difficult time trying to figure out how to create a folder programmatically using either REST or HTTP methods. Whenever I try to make a POST with an item data I get the following error

Invalid slug header for BLOBs. Slug headers must be server- or web-relative URL of the file. Server-relative URLs begins with a forward slash (\"/\").

Can anyone please help.

Many thanks in advance.

Dinesh

Comment: No One has any idea about this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Get items

To get all items you can either call this url:

```
http://yourhost/_vti_bin/ListData.svc/YourLib
```

Or you can call this url:

```
http://yourhost/_vti_bin/Lists.asmx
```

with this payload:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance'
    xmlns:xsd='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema' 
    xmlns:soap='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/'>
  <soap:Body>
    <GetListItems xmlns='http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/'>
      <listName>YourLib</listName>
    </GetListItems>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

### Create folder

I can't say if this is the correct approach, but it should work.
It uses `Batch`  which I find a bit scary, but I have used this myself with success.
To create a folder you can call this url:

```
http://yourhost/sites/wf/_vti_bin/Lists.asmx
```

with this payload:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance' 
    xmlns:xsd='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema' 
    xmlns:soap='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/'>
  <soap:Body>
    <UpdateListItems xmlns='http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/'>
      <listName>YourLib</listName>
      <updates>
        <Batch OnError='Continue' PreCalc='TRUE' ListVersion='0' >
          <Method ID='1' Cmd='New'>
            <Field Name='FSObjType'>1</Field>
            <Field Name='BaseName'>YourFolder</Field>
          </Method>
        </Batch>
      </updates>
    </UpdateListItems>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Comment: Thanks eirikb. It work for me. You have any idea how to create a nested folders?

Comment: Thanks eirikb and for nested folders I did

      <Field Name='BaseName'>YourFolder/NestedFolder</Field>

Comment: Hey. Sorry I haven't had time to look into it. Great that you found a solution for nested folders :)

Answer (score 2):

As Tommy pointed out and according to [3.1.4.3 Document](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd962796(v=office.12).aspx):

> Inserting new documents to a document library involve sending a POST
>   request containing the contents of the document to the EntitySet
>   representing the document library. The protocol client **MUST include
>   the SLUG header** (as specified in [RFC5023](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=114658) section 9.7) whose value
>   is the name of the file that is being created in their POST requests.

### How to create Folder via REST in SharePoint 2010

```
function createFolder(webUrl,listName,folderName,folderPath, success, failure) {

    var folderPayload = {
      'ContentType': 'Folder',
      'Title' : folderName,
      'Path' : folderPath
    };

    $.ajax({
        url: webUrl + "/_vti_bin/listdata.svc/" + listName,
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json;odata=verbose",
        data: JSON.stringify(folderPayload),
        headers: {
            "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
            "Slug": folderPath + "/" + folderName + "|0x0120" 
        },
        success: function (data) {
            success(data.d);
        },
        error: function (data) {
            failure(data.responseJSON.error);
        }
    });
}
```

Examples:

1 Create root folder named `Orders` in the `Documents` library

```
createFolder('https://intranet.contoso.com','Documents','Orders', '/Shared Documents',function(folder){
    console.log('Folder ' + folder.Name + ' has been created succesfully'); 
  },
  function(error){
    console.log(JSON.stringify(error));
  }
);
```

2 Create sub folder named `2014` under the folder `Orders` in the `Documents` library

```
createFolder('https://intranet.contoso.com','Documents','2014', '/Shared Documents/Orders',function(folder){
    console.log('Folder ' + folder.Name + ' has been created succesfully'); 
  },
  function(error){
    console.log(JSON.stringify(error));
  }
);
```

Comment: I've tried same ListData.svc approach on SP 2012 (it supports old interface) and succeed even without `folderPayload` - just did not send body at all. Unfortunately I have no write-access to SP 2010 sites - it may be different there, but anyway it's quire strange!

Answer (score 1):

I don't have high enough reputation to comment, but I already gave the answer to this over here: [Folder creation in Document library using listdata.svc](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/70896/folder-creation-in-document-library-using-listdata-svc)

On creating folders in lists, its the same way, but without the "slug" header and you just add "/Lists" to beginning of the "Path" property.

Comment: I'll flag it for you.