# Bad Request: When creating new Folder in Sharepoint 2010 list

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-foundation

Trying to create New Folder using the below javascript methods.
URL: http://hostname.com/project/Portal
Inside this URL and the in the 'ParentList' am trying to create new Folder by name 'Order 2015' inside a parent folder 'Folder1'.

Please refer the code below,

```
 function createFolder1(webUrl, listName, folderOptions) {
            var folderPayload = folderOptions;
            debugger
            folderPayload['Title'] = folderOptions.Url.split('/').pop();
            folderPayload['Path'] = folderOptions.Url.split('/').slice(0, -1).join('/');

            //Create Folder resource
            return $.ajax({
                url: webUrl + "/_vti_bin/listdata.svc/" + listName,
                type: "POST",
                contentType: "application/json;odata=verbose",
                data: JSON.stringify(folderPayload),
                headers: {
                    "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
                    "Slug": folderOptions.Url + "|" + folderOptions.ContentTypeId
                }
            });
        }
        function createDocumentSet(webUrl, listName, docSetOptions) {
            docSetOptions.ContentTypeId = '0x0120D520';
            return createFolder1(webUrl, listName, docSetOptions);
        }


var webUrl = "http://hostname.com/project/Portal";
                var listName = 'ParentList';
                var docSetOptions = {
                    'Url': '/Folder1/Orders2015'
                };
                createDocumentSet(webUrl, listName, docSetOptions)
                .then(function (data) {
                    var itemProperties = {
                        'Description': 'Orders 2015',
                        'StartDate': '2015-06-23T07:00:00Z'
                    };
                    return updateFolderProperties(data.d, itemProperties)
                })
                .done(function () {                    
                    console.log('Document Set has been created succesfully');
                })
                .fail(function (error) {                    
                    console.log(JSON.stringify(error));
                });
```

This is throwing the bad request error. I am not able to figure why is this issue. Can someone please let me know the right way to achieve it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Look at this: https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/112680/2853

Comment: Hey Thanks, Its working... I could able to create a root folder but not a subfolder. Its throwing 500 Server error..