# Create a folder using REST and HttpWebRequest in SharePoint 2010

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-server, rest

I can get all the items from a library using the following code:

```
  HttpWebRequest endpointRequest = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create("http://website/_vti_bin/ListData.svc/SharedDocuments");

        endpointRequest.Method = "GET";
        endpointRequest.Accept = "application/json;odata=verbose";           
        NetworkCredential cred = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("Administrator", password);
        endpointRequest.Credentials = cred;
        HttpWebResponse endpointResponse = (HttpWebResponse)endpointRequest.GetResponse();
        try
        {
            WebResponse webResponse = endpointRequest.GetResponse();
            Stream webStream = webResponse.GetResponseStream();
            StreamReader responseReader = new StreamReader(webStream);
            string response = responseReader.ReadToEnd();
            JObject jobj = JObject.Parse(response);
            JArray jarr = (JArray)jobj["d"]["results"];
            foreach (JObject j in jarr)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(j["Title"] );
            }

            responseReader.Close();
            Console.ReadLine();


        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.Out.WriteLine(e.Message); Console.ReadLine();
        }
```

Apart from changing the method to POST, how can I create a folder in the library in this way?

I am familiar with [How to create a folder in SharePoint 2010 document library using REST or HTTP methods](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/50997/how-to-create-a-folder-in-sharepoint-2010-document-library-using-rest-or-http-me) and would prefer to avoid using SOAP.